# Symfony 3 connection to multiple databases

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

```
dynamic:
driver:   %database_driver%
host:     %database_host%
port:     %database_port%
dbname:   %database name%
user:     %database_user%
password: %database_password%
charset:  UTF8
```

Hi everybody

I would like to connect to multiple databases dynamically. I read this tutorial http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html and it works as it was explained.

But my only problem is to change the value of dbname directly from my Controller to connect to all my databases.

It will be 24 hours that I am on this problem. if you have ideas I really need it

Comment: Just to be sure, you have separate database servers, right? Not just different schema on the same server?

Comment: I have a master database that lists the databases of the companies, the companies one has the choice to use a model A or a model B, the databases are saved locally

Comment: The same as @Don'tPanic and if you could post the full database .configuration

Comment: I have not implemented it yet, that's why I'm asking for help

Comment: Are the databases variables or always the same in master database?

Comment: yes, in the master database, there are two fields, the first contains the name of the database, the second contains the type of model (A or B)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code example shows only one connection. You've to define to database connection, like the example from [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html):

## Easy hack: don't use an entity manager, but just connection.

If you want an easy way out, don't use an EntityManager at all. It might be overkill if you only want to get some information about the database and don't want to store information or use Entities. Then, just create a custom connection and use 'vanilla' SQL:

```
$this->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory')->createConnection($params);
```

Your question does not say how many database you expect. So let's describe two possibilities: a small number of (fixed) database or a dynamic connection.

## Multiple connections, the simple way

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            model_a:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_hosta%'
                port:     '%database_porta%'
                dbname:   '%database_namea%'
                user:     '%database_usera%'
                password: '%database_passworda%'
                charset:  UTF8
            model_b:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_hostb%'
                port:     '%database_portb%'
                dbname:   '%database_nameb%'
                user:     '%database_userb%'
                password: '%database_passwordb%'
                charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
            model_a:
                connection: model_a
            model_b:
                connection: model_b
```

By default, connection `default` will be used. In your controller, you can switch to another connection:

```
$customerEm = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('model_a');
```

And of course, you can dynamically choose your Manager:

```
//just an example, I don't know how you choose which database to use.
$managerName = $company->getModelName();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($managerName);
```

## Dynamically create EntityManager

The `DoctrineBundle` has no support for dynamic values (other than configured values like the first example). You can [create your own EntityManager](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html), if you don't want (or can't) define multiple connections because the dynamic table name.

Create a factory and define it a service:

```
class EntityManagerFactory
{
    public function createManager($dbname)
    {
        $isDevMode = false;
        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
        // or if you prefer yaml or XML
        //$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
        //$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/yaml"), $isDevMode);

        $conn = [
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'username' => 'foo',
            'password' => 'foo',
            'dbname' => $dbname
        ];

        // obtaining the entity manager
        return EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
    }
}
```

And use it in your controller:

```
public function controllerAction()
{
    $em = $this->get(EntityManagerFactory::class)->getManager('model-name');
}
```

Comment: Stephane thank you, so I use the second solution, if I want to use the entities provided for model b, with the manager I just created, it is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by second solution? Dynamically create EntityManager?

Comment: yes, i use Dynamically create EntityManager.I would like to use the entities

Comment: Please give some background information about your system. What do you mean by 'the entities'? Do you have 1 model with multiple databases (table structure identical, only data differs)? Or two models (A and B) and my database that are based on A or B?

Comment: Just for the sake of completness. Shouldn't the second part of the second solutions be something like: "$em = $this->get(EntityManagerFactory::class)->createManager('model-name');" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
$connectionParams = array(
    'dbname' => 'mydb',
    'user' => 'user',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    );
*/
             
$connectionParams = array(
    'url' => 'mysql://user:secret@localhost/mydb',
    );
            
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams);
```