# Dynamically set Schema for ORM Entity in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have an application and its data is stored in MySQL. For security purposes, each user's data is stored in a separate database(schema) on that server. The structure of the tables inside are the same for all users/databases.

I am using Symfony 4. I created a doctrine connection and an Entity for the user's settings (table user_settings). However, I need to be able to use that entity for different schemas(databases)

**How can I dynamically set the database in runtime for the EntityManager ?**

I want to clarify that the number of databases (users) is unknown, so I can not pre-set all of the possible DBs in my config.

Comment: Please have a look into that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313830/symfony-3-connection-to-multiple-databases This should be working on sf4 as well

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, Symfony 4 is not designed to work with multiple databases at once and has no default functionality to set the schema on the fly.
In the comment from Fabien Papet, responding to my question, he gave a link to another question, which describes a few ways to work around this.
I am marking the question as a duplicate of that one

Answer (score 0):

This should help; https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

You'll find some answers on that page that will also be specific for what you're after.

Comment: I have seen the documentation and it does not reference dynamically setting a database.