# Symfony 4: Connect to database manually / Create a dynamic entity manager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm working on a Symfony 4 Web Project, and I have a database for every Client, so, in every request I have to connect to a database based on client id.

How to use doctrine to connect to a database manually ?

## MyController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/log", name="log", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function log(Request $request)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(['ROLE_CLIENT','ROLE_ADMIN']);
    $clientId = $request->query->get('client_id');
    
    $dbName = 'project_'.$clientId;            

    //I have database credentials: $host,$port,$username,$password & $dbName:

    
    $this->getDoctrine()->........
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 3 connection to multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313830/symfony-3-connection-to-multiple-databases)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with multiple connections and managers. Here the [official symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

So, if you could change manually *config/packages/doctrine.yaml*, you will solve your problem.

Another way, is to work with entity manager directly:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array('/path/to/entity/mapping/files');

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths);
$dbParams = array('driver' => 'pdo_sqlite', 'memory' => true);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

[Entity Manager API documenation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.html)

Comment: for the first sol, I can't declare 200 database & I want that the solution be more dynamic, for the 2nd sol, u write the code as a PHP application, can u write the code in a Symfony Controller ?

Comment: Yes, of course. Use EntityManager in your symfony controller directly, how in the example above. Using EntityManager from DI container you can work only with connections from your .yml config. Using directly, you can dinamically manage you connections.